# mac M1 cocoapods correct architecture? flutter run won't install pods properly

Tags: flutter, cocoapods, apple-m1

I am having some issues with cocoapods and architecture i think on my mac M1. Here is what I get when I do `flutter run`

[image: console output]

I think it is a problem with architecture. when i run `arch` in my terminal it shows `i386`

However when I run arch from vscode terminal this is what I get
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Try to uninstall all `cocoapods` and gem

`sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`

And install again using `brew`

`brew install cocoapods`

Then clean all your `pods`. run this command on your terminal

```
flutter clean
rm -Rf ios/Pods
rm ios/Podfile.lock
rm -Rf ios/.symlinks
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have fixed this already, but for anyone else this just worked for me with a similar problem on my M1 Macbook Pro:

```
flutter clean
rm ios/Podfile.lock
flutter pub get
cd ios
arch -x86_64 pod repo update
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Not sure why your terminal gives a different architecture than inside VS Code. Mine are the same.